# Getting from cart content the post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am trying to grab the post id from WooCommerce cart content so I can access an advanced custom field number I have set. I am not able to find a post ID value only a product ID value which will not work.

This is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {

global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;
$service_charge =0;
$cart_contents =($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents);
foreach($cart_contents as $cart_contents =>$values) {
    $post_values = $values['data']->post;
    $post_id = $post_values->ID;
    $value = get_field( 'service_charge', $post_id );
}
```

How can I get the post ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a little bit your code, and now you will get correctly the item ID to use with ACF plugin **`get_field(`**) function.

This is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $service_charge = 0;

    // As you can have multiple items in cart we will save all values in an indexed array.
    $service_charge_values_array = array();

    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $item) {
        $item_id = $item['data']->id;

        // Each stored value has a corresponding key that is the item ID
        $service_charge_values_array[$item_id] = get_field( 'service_charge', $item_id );
    }

    // . . .
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This is tested and works.

---

> **Update**
>
> As you can have multiple items in your cart, I have changed the code a little bit and I store now the data in an array in which for each **`item ID`** is stored in the **`key`** with a corresponding **`value`** of **`'service_charge'`**.